# 'Connection refused' connecting through TCP/IP

Tags: c#, tcp, network-programming, tcpclient, tcpserver

I want to connect unity app on android with a computer application. I could run it on the network but over internet it is always saying the machine is refusing the connection. I have disabled the firewall of windows and anti-virus but still have problem connecting the server and Android client:

```
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

Here is the code:

Server side:

```
TcpListener tcpListener;
Socket socket;
NetworkStream networkStream;
Thread thread;

string getIpAddress()
{
    System.Net.IPHostEntry host;
    string localIp = "";
    host = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(System.Net.Dns.GetHostName());
    foreach (System.Net.IPAddress ip in host.AddressList)
    {
        localIp = ip.ToString();
    }
    return localIp;
}

public void ReceiveImage()
{
    try
    {
        IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse("95.171.54.53");
        tcpListener = new TcpListener(localAddr, 53100);
        tcpListener.Start();
        socket = tcpListener.AcceptSocket();
        networkStream = new NetworkStream(socket);
        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(networkStream);
        if (socket.Connected == true)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                tcpListener.Stop();
                ReceiveImage();
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        string Message = ex.Message;
    }
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ReceiveImage));
    thread.Start();
}

private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    tcpListener.Stop();
    thread.Abort();
}
```

This is the client side:

```
// Update is called once per frame
int frameSaveCount = -1;
int FrameCount = -1;
Socket socket;
NetworkStream networkStream;
Thread thread;
MemoryStream memoryStream;
TcpClient tcpClient;
BinaryWriter binaryWriter;

void Update()
{
    // ...
    if(FrameCount % 10==0)
    {
        // ...
        send(bytes);
    }
}

void send(Byte[] bytes)
{
    try
    {
        print(getIpAddress());
        tcpClient = new TcpClient("95.171.54.53", 53100);
        networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
        binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(networkStream);
        binaryWriter.Write(bytes);
        binaryWriter.Close();
        networkStream.Close();
        tcpClient.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        string message = exception.Message;
        print(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a firewall on the server that might refuse the connection? Can you connect using telnet on the client? Or another arbitrary machine? I would first check if the server is reachable, then go on to debugging the client-server connection.

Comment: Is the server actually hosted on a network that's set up to host servers?

Comment: Your server-side exception handling is unacceptably rudimentary.

Comment: I would hide your ip if I were you...

Comment: Hi, well i have tried alot until i figured out for connecting two computers over network we should do port forwarding, however its what i dont know at all about!

Answer (score 1):

> the machine is refusing the connection

This error has exactly one meaning: nothing was listening at the IP:port you tried to connect to. So, either it was wrong, or your server wasn't started when your client tried to connect.

Image files have precisely nothing to do with it.